# React Native elements list item switch not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a SectionList with a RN elements ListItem, I have hidden the chevron and set the switch state to a state variable. the onSwitch method is not working, or at least i cant get it to work.

I have tried a few different ways of implementing it to no avail.

```
 <SectionList
            sections={[
                {title: 'Company Focus', data: this.state.focusNodes},
            ]}
            renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <Text style= 
            {styles.sectionHeader}>{section.title}</Text>}
            renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem style={styles.subTitle} key= 
            {item.id} title={item.name} 
            switchButton hideChevron switched= 
            {this.state.isNodeSelected} switchOnTintColor={'#00BCD4'} 

            onSwitch={(value) => {
               this._handleSwitch(value);

            }}/>} />




 _handleSwitch = (item) => {
    this.state.isNodeSelected = true;
    console.log(item);
    console.log(this.state.isNodeSelected);
    }
```

The other way:

```
    onSwitch={(value) => {
          this.setState(previousState => {
          return{previousState, isNodeSelected: value}})
                    }}/>} />
```

The switch in the first example just moves then moves back. In the second example it moves all the switches in the list to on or off regardless of which one i switch on/off

EDIT - THE WHOLE COMPONENT :)

```
  'use strict';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, 
  Text, 
  View,
  NavigatorIOS,
  ScrollView,
  Button, 
  PickerIOS,
  Dimensions,
  SectionList,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';
import {Header, ListItem, List} from 'react-native-elements';

import StepIndicator from 'react-native-step-indicator';

export default class FocusPage extends React.Component {

            constructor(props){
                super(props);
                this.state ={
                    data : [],
                    roleNodes: [],
                    skillNodes: [],
                    focusNodes: [],
                    // roleSelection: '',                
                    // childSelection: '',
                    isVisible: false,
                    currentPosition: 0,
                    selectedNodes: [],
                    isFocusNodeSelected: false
                }         
            }

            _createFocusNodesArray = (array) => {
                var nodeArray =[];
                for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){      
                    if(array[i].orderNumber === 2)                    
                    nodeArray.push(array[i]);        
                }
                return nodeArray;
            }

                _getFocusData = () => {
                    fetch('http://10.0.0.58:8082/api/getfocusnodes', {
                        method: 'GET'
                        })
                        .then((response) => response.json())  
                        .then((responseJson) => {

                        //   this.setState({
                        //     data: responseJson
                        //   })
                        var simpleArray = 
                        this._simplifyJsonArray(responseJson);
                        // console.log(simpleArray);
                        this.setState({
                            focusNodes: 
                        this._createFocusNodesArray(simpleArray),

                        })

                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);

                        //   this.setState({
                        //     isLoading: false,
                        //     message: 'Woops! ' + error
                        //   })
                        })     
                }

            //'http://10.0.0.58:8082/api/gettreenodes'
            //'http://192.168.6.217:8082/api/gettreenodes'
        componentDidMount = () => {
           this._getFocusData();
        }


        _simplifyJsonArray = (array) => {

            var tempArray = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                var tempNode = {
                    id: array[i].id,
                    name: array[i].name,
                    orderNumber: array[i].orderNumber,
                    isSelected: false
                }
                    tempArray.push(tempNode);  
            }
            return tempArray;
        }

        getSelection = (selectedItem) => {

            console.log(selectedItem);
            // selectedItem.isSelected = true;
            // this.state.isNodeSelected = true;

            for (let index = 0; index < this.state.focusNodes.length; 
              index++) {
                const element = this.state.focusNodes[index];
                if(element.name === selectedItem){
                    console.log(element.name);
                    this.state.isFocusNodeSelected = true;
                }
            }

            if (selectedItem.isSelected) {
                this.state.isFocusNodeSelected = true;
            }
            // console.log(this.state.isNodeSelected);          
            // for (let i = 0; i < this.state.focusNodes.length; i++) {
            //     const element = this.state.focusNodes[i];
            //     if (element.name === selectedItem) {
            //         element.isSelected = true;
            //         this.state.isNodeSelected = element.isSelected;
            //         this.state.selectedNodes.push(element);   
            //         console.log(this.state.isNodeSelected);          
            //     }
            //     else{
            //         this.state.isNodeSelected = false;
            //     }               
            // }          
            // console.log('The selected item: ' + selectedItem);
            // console.log('The selected Array: ' + this.state.selectedNodes);
        }

_handleSwitch = (item) => {
    this.state.isFocusNodeSelected = true;
    console.log(item);
    console.log(this.state.isFocusNodeSelected);
}




  render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                     <SectionList
                    sections={[
                        {title: 'Company Focus', data: this.state.focusNodes},
                    ]}
                    renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <Text style={styles.sectionHeader}>{section.title}</Text>}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem style={styles.subTitle} key={item.id} title={item.name} 
                    switchButton hideChevron switched={item.isSelected} switchOnTintColor={'#00BCD4'} 
                    onSwitch={(value) => {
                        this.setState(previousState => {
                            return{previousState, isFocusNodeSelected: value}
                        })
                    }}/>} />

            </View>
        );
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  pageTitle:{
      fontSize: 27,
      textAlign: 'center',
      //margin: 20
  },
  sectionHeader:{
    fontSize: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#673AB7',
    height: 40,
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: 10,
    color: 'white'

  },
  subTitle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    // textAlign: 'center',
    // marginTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#00BCD4'
  },
  popButton: {
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 5,
    // marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#00BCD4',
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  subtitleView: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingTop: 5,
    textAlign: 'right'

  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, the reason why your switches get flipped back is because you are always setting your switches to `true`, so they can never get set to `false`:

```
this.state.isNodeSelected = true;
```

That's not the only problem though. As you see in your second example, you fix this by setting the value to what get's passed into `onSwitch` as `value`. That's good. Now the issue of having all switches flip is because you are using the same `state` value for **all switches**.

```
switched={this.state.isNodeSelected}
```

So what is happening is that when you update `isNodeSelected`, you are updating it for every switch.

To fix this, you need to hold the `switched` value for each `ListItem` somewhere; probably the most straightforward would be in what you pass to `sections`.

```
sections={[
  {title: 'Company Focus', data: this.state.focusNodes},
]}
```

The data you pass into your `sections` prop should be kept in your `state` so you can update the specific item that whose switch is flipped. However, without seeing your `state` code, it's hard to tell what you're doing and how exactly to fix it. The above explanation should be enough to get you to a solution though. Just remember that `renderItem` also gets an `index` argument which are shown in the [simple examples from the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html) and explained further in the [prop docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html#renderitem).

**Edit:** With the edited in info and changes, we now have a `renderItem` where each `ListItem` has its own `switched` value stored in `item.isSelected`. So given that, our goal is to have a `onSwitch` that updates *just that value* for *just that item*. So what do we update?

Well, the `SectionList`'s `sections` prop is getting that data from `this.state.focusNodes` (what `data` is set to). So updating the correct value in `focusNodes` is what needs to happen. As I alluded to above, one way to do this is to leverage `renderItem`'s `index` argument:

```
renderItem={({item, index}) => 
  <ListItem
    style={styles.subTitle}
    key={item.id}
    title={item.name} 
    switchButton
    hideChevron
    switched={item.isSelected}
    switchOnTintColor={'#00BCD4'} 
    onSwitch={(value) => {
      let focusNodes = [...this.state.focusNodes];
      focusNodes[index].isSelected = value;
      this.setState({ focusNodes, isFocusNodeSelected: value });
    }}
  />
}
```

**Notes**:

- I used `index` to figure out which of the `focusNodes` needs to get updated. Since you are using `SectionList`, read the docs to understand how this `index` value gets determined. Be careful and don't make assumptions once you start using multiple sections. I say this because...
- I noticed that `data` in your `state` is unused. If you eventually refactor and change your `sections` prop to use this instead or you move `focusNodes` into that, you'll have to refactor what is being updated. Take care and understand how your data is structured and not make a bad assumption about `index`.
- In case the missing `previousState` threw you off, I used a shorthand in `setState` to make it cleaner.
- I'm making the assumption that the `value` being passed to `onSwitch` is the correct boolean value that `isSelected` needs to be updated to. I don't have a test project setup to run this to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I get my data from my api and store it in state as an array, i also have the isFocusNodeSelected bool there. In the array each object has an isSelected bool also. How would i go about using that?

Comment: @molebox Edit in that information and code into your question and clean up the indents. I'll update my answer once it's more clear exactly what your data structure looks like.

Comment: I have used the renderItem index as key={item.id}, Im just not sure how to set the state of an item in a list via the onSwitch callback. I get where you are going though...

Comment: I have added the whole component, would really appreciate any input you might have to solve this issue. Ive only been playing about with React Native for 3 days (c# background) so am still getting used to all this malarky :)

Comment: @molebox No need to say sorry. Live and learn and pass it forward. I updated with what I think should be the correct way to handle this (I can't run the code at the moment so hopefully no typos or mistakes). Since you're coming from a C# background, my one suggestion is to read up on how JavaScript handles async, Promises, and about mutability (and ES5, ES6, ES7 syntax). These are all really key to React which React Native is built on top of. There's a lot more to it, but just having those down will cut down on a lot of growing pains.

Comment: Oh my word you legend! As i said im new to javascript and es6 syn, anyway thank you so much! I didnt know about using arrays in that way - ' focusNodes[index].isSelected = value;'. Thanks again

Comment: thank you, I’ll definitely have a read. Been winging it so far but deeper knowledge is needed if im going to progress and really understand how it all works. Thanks again for the help.